# Adding inline labels to python contourf plot screw up plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm having a strange error trying to add inline contour labels to my contourf plot.

I have a netcdf file which I am pulling data from. The issue appears to be specific with using data from this file (I cannot seem to recreate it otherwise).

Here is the netcdf file:
http://www.filedropper.com/cm1out

Here is my code without the line to add the inline labels:

```
nc = Dataset('cm1out.nc')

z = nc['z'][:]
x = nc['xf'][:]

u  = nc['u'][:]
uc = plt.contourf(xs,z,u[5,:,30,:], cmap = 'coolwarm')
```

Resulting in this plot:
[image]

Adding the following line...

```
plt.clabel(uc, fmt='%2.1f', colors='k', fontsize=14, inline = 1)
```

Results in this plot:
[image]

Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: No idea what's happening there, but you could try to add a `contour` on top, and set the clabels to the `contour` instead of the `contourf`; then set the lines to invisible or linewidth to 0 or something similar.